# Exec format error when compiling C file for Python extension

Tags: c, python-2.7, gcc, archlinux-arm

I am trying to extend python using a simple C file.  I succeeded in creating my own python module, but I also need the C file itself to compile and run as a standalone executable.  I can successfully compile it, but when I try to run it I get the error "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

Here is my C source file (hellomodule.c):

```
#include <Python.h>

void print_hello(const char* name){
    printf("Hello %s!\n", name);
}

//Only used by Python
static PyObject*
say_hello(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    const char* name;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &name))
        return NULL;

    //printf("Hello %s!\n", name);
    print_hello("World");

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

//Only used by Python
static PyMethodDef HelloMethods[] =
{
    {"say_hello", say_hello, METH_VARARGS, "Greet somebody."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

//Only used by Python
PyMODINIT_FUNC
inithello(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("hello", HelloMethods);
}

int main(){
    print_hello("World");
}
```

I can "successfully" compile it without any errors or warnings with the following:

```
gcc -I /usr/include/python2.7 -c hellomodule.c -o hellomodule
```

After making the "hellomodule" file executable, I run it and get the error:

```
-bash: ./hellomodule: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Why would this be causing such an error?

Comment: You are not supposed to execute the module!!!

Comment: `-c` means "compile". This stage produces object files, not binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute an object file, that is not an executable. To compile your code as a module you need something like

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 \
    -shared hellomodule.c -o hellomodule.so -lpython2.7
```

but to link correctly to everything and add all the possible include directories there is a script called `python-config` you just need to invoke it like this

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 `python-config --includes` \
    -shared hellomodule.c -o hellomodule.so `python-config --libs`
```

and even better, the script provides`CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` too, so finally

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 `python-config --cflags` \
    -shared hellomodule.c -o hellomodule.so `python-config --ldflags`
```

and then, copy the resulting file to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

After that, you can load the module in a python script like this

```python
import hellomodule
```

Object files are intermediate binary files used ultimately by the linker (*`ld` probably*) to produce the final binary. A python module has no `main()` function and it has to be a runtime loadable shared object which exports some predefined symbols that the python interpreter will use to load the module into the python script/program.

Note: To correctly do this and not die trying create a Makefile, like this

```python
CFLAGS = `python-config --cflags` -Wall -Werror # add more if needed
LDFLAGS = `python-config --ldflags` # add more if needed
OBJS = hellomodule.o # add more if needed

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o modulename.so $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

ensure that you use *tabs* instead of spaces for indentation, and then run `make` in the same directory where the *Makefile* and the source files are.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know what the "-c" option meant.  When I take it out it says I have a bunch of undefined references to python objects.  Also, in the question I said that I already have the python module working.  I am trying to get the C file to compile and run on its own.

Comment: Yes because you need `-lpython2.7`, let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I added the "-lpython2.7" and now it compiles and runs correctly!